# How to hint vscode about the file type within the file?

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, filenames

Visual Studio Code documentation for [Language Identifiers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) explains how to map file extensions to language definitions.

**Is there a way to provide this hint within the file itself?**

- A possibility could be to have this information in a comment. I realize that in order to have this, one must first know what a comment is (and it varies by language, which is not known yet, thus some catch-22 situation).
- Another one could be the special meaning of the first line of the file.

None such possibilities were provided in the documentation, I am asking the question in case there is something else available anyway (through an extension for instance)